# How to add checkbox in ajax return data table and get the value of the checked checkbox in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

Dear mentors i am working on a asp.net core mvc .net 6 project where i have a view in which i am making a ajax call to load data to a datatable

the ajax call and the datatable loads script is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    url: "/HRValidation/Indexresult",
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $('#example').dataTable({
                            data: response,
                            columns: [
                                {
                                    targets: 0,
                                    data: null,
                                    className: 'text-center',
                                    searchable: false,
                                    orderable: false,
                                    render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                        return '&lt;input type="checkbox" class="_check" name="check" value="' + full.employeeId + '"&gt;';
                                    },
                                    width: "5%"
                                },
                                { 'data': 'employeeName' },
                                { 'data': 'employeeEmail' },
                                { 'data': 'employeePersonalNumber' },
                                { 'data': 'employeeDateofJoining' },
                                { 'data': 'employeePermanentCity' },
                                { 'data': 'employeePermanentState' },
                                { 'data': 'employeePermanentCountry' },
                                { 'data': 'totalErrors' },
                                {
                                    mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                                        return '&lt;a href="/HRDashboard/Edit/' + row.employeeId + '" class="bi bi-pen"&gt;&lt;/a&gt; ';
                                    }
                                },
                            ],
                            autofill: true,
                            select: true,
                            responsive: true,
                            destroy: true,
                            scrollY: true,
                            scrollX: true,

                        })

                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }

                });
            });
        }
```

all i am trying is that if some of the checkboxes are checked and if its related button is pressed an on click function should execute and it a ajax query

what i have tried is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#assigned").click(function () {
                var values = $('input[type="checkbox"].myCheckbox:checked').map(function () {
                    return $(this).val();
                }).toArray();
                //var checkedIds = $('.chkBxClass:checkbox:checked').map(function () { return this.value; }).get().join(',');
                //console.log(checkedIds);
                //var hriss = document.getElementById("hr").value;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    url: "/HRValidation/AssignToHR",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ name: checkedIds, hris: hriss }),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);

                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }

                });
            });
        });
```

i need to pass the checkbox values as array because i the controller i need to perform an operation using foreach loop and make changes in the db.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is part of your code not working as expected?  What is happening?

Comment: "_this my div_" - Where is that?

Comment: @james on click the ajax is not working and sometimes getting response is not defined or 500 error

Comment: @andrewJames i am sorry i did not post the div code , i have removed it because it just contains the button to make the ajax call.

Comment: 500 means some server code broke when you sent your Ajax request.  Possibly you didn’t send the data in the format it was expecting but it could be something else wrong in the server code.

Comment: @james yeah you are right , but the issue is i am not able to get the check box values as array in by using this ''''var values = $('input[type="checkbox"].myCheckbox:checked').map(function () {
                    return $(this).val();
                }).toArray();
````

Comment: You’re not sending `values` you’re sending `checkedIds`

Comment: yeah you are right but the array is still empty.

Comment: I recommend using DataTables support for this - see [an example here](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html). This provides a simple API for [selecting all the checked records](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/integration).

Comment: As an aside: Your approach will not work because it will not find selected records which are not in the currently displayed page. The data is in the DataTable, but not all of that data is displayed in the web page - only one page of the DataTables data is displayed at any one time.